# Конвертация Javascript кода в PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть JS-код:

```
GgX=((!+[]+!![]+[])+(+[]))+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));
GgX*=+((+!![]+[])+(+!![])); 
GgX-=+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]));
abb = parseInt(GgX, 10)+10;
alert(abb);
```

22503 - результат

Нужно переписать его на php. Подскажите:

1. Что за "[]" и что вообще выполняет данный код, желательно по шагам или описание операций.
2. Аналог parseInt в php.
3. Есть ли какой-либо php-скрипт/эмулятор, позволяющий выполнять подобный javascript код именно на стороне сервера?

Спасибо!

Comment: Всее! Задачка для первоклассников оказывается))
Вопросы 1 и 2 снимаю полностью.
Вопрос 3 остается актуальный - нужен совет, не хочется воротить по схеме php -> nodejs -> php :(

Comment: А можете показать решение "задачки для первоклассников"?

Answer (score 3):

[[@Murky](/users/27488/murky)](/users/27488/murky), для того, чтобы выполнить JavaScript из PHP вам понадобится установит на сервере соответствующий модуль, например, [v8js](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.v8js.php).

[[@Angus123](/users/3537/angus123)](/users/3537/angus123), решение "задачки для первоклассников" станет очевидным, если вспомнить, что JavaScript - динамически типизированный язык, и при попытке совершить над объектом действие, которое к этому объекту неприменимо, JavaScript попытается привести этот объект к подходящему типу. В частности операция "унарный плюс" неприменима к массивам, зато применима к числам. Пустой массив JavaScript приведёт к 0, массив с одним числом - к этому числу, массив, содержащий больше одного элемента - к `NaN`. Таким образом, выражение `+[]` приводится к 0. Логическое отрицание неприменимо к числам, поэтому JavaScript осуществляет конвертацию `0 -> false`. Таким образом, выражение `!+[] = true`. Аналогичным образом `!![] = true`. Бинарное сложение к булевским значениям неприменимо, поэтому они конвертируются обратно в числа: `!+[]+!![] = true + true = 1 + 1 = 2`. Зная о подобных преобразованиях, легко вычислить значение представленного выражения.

Comment: Вот те чудеса... Не знал, спасибо :)